# Where is DataGrid RowDeleted event?

Tags: wpf, events, datagrid, wpftoolkit

Hello I am looking for an event I can handle for row deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using an event on the DataGrid you should use a collection as its ItemsSource which supports change notification. Unfortunately the de-facto standard "ObservableCollection" does not support an event that fires *before* an item is removed, but it's quite easy to derive your own collection class from ObservableCollection which overrides RemoveItem and raises an appropriate event that can be cancelled.

Comment: Sounds fair enough, any further suggestions will be welcommed.